# ARSCNView.delegate is nil even i set to self

Tags: ios, swift, arscnview

I have a sceneview in my controller and i set its delegate to self but its delegate methods are not getting called. While debugging, i set delegate to self but its not working. Please help. Here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self
    // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true
    // Create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene()
    // Set the scene to the view
    sceneView.scene = scene
}
```

Here scenview exist but scenview.delegate = 0x0.
Please help

Comment: Would you mind to share your full code?

Comment: have you conform to the protocol in the class line?

Comment: What is `self`. Do you keep a strong reference to it anywhere?

Comment: @VincentJoy yes I have confirmed

Comment: @JeremyP I am using just single controller app